# Выражения в шаблонизаторе Django

Tags: python, django, шаблонизаторы

Делаю интернет-магазин, и появилась надобность отображать суммарную стоимость товара с учётом выбранного количества. С пересчётом цены в процессе изменения количества проблем не возникло, но возникла проблема с отображением стоимости при начальной прогрузке страницы

В шаблон передаётся объект `item`, у которого есть атрибуты `price` и `min_count`, и мне необходимо в шаблоне вывести их произведение.

Jinja позволяет использовать выражение в виде:

```
{{ item.min_count * item.price }}
```

Однако в шаблонизаторе Django это приводит к ошибке:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /detail/item/2/
Could not parse the remainder: ' * item.price' from 'item.min_count * item.price'
```

Можно ли каким-либо образом вывести произведение значений двух полей? Не хотелось бы вручную его туда впихивать через JS

Comment: Посчитать заранее в views

Comment: Если `item` это Django-модель, то можно добавить проперти вроде `sum_price` и сосчитать всё внутри реализации этого проперти и дальше просто `{{ item.sum_price }}`

Comment: @andreymal т.е. этот шаблонизатор не позволяет просчитывать арифметические операции. Если у меня будет 20 атрибутов, и мне нужны будут попарно произведения всех, то мне нужно будет 380 проперти для каждой пары атрибутов, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Зачем, ничто не мешает сделать список и пройтись по нему циклом (циклы в шаблонизаторе всё-таки есть)

Comment: Эх, костыли, костыли.. Ну да ладно, спасибо. В следующих проектах, наверное, буду подкидывать Jinja в качестве шаблонизатора, чтобы не страдать подобными непотребствами

Comment: Считать — это не задача шаблонизатора, так что в данном конкретном случае Django делает всё правильно. Задача шаблонизатора — вывести заранее заготовленные, посчитанные бизнес-логикой данные.